# Ruby - How to create log file by limiting file size using Logger?

Tags: ruby, logging

I want to create a log file with default file size limit and once it reaches the file size,a new log file has to be created.

I referred Logger in ruby doc and they had an example like this

> logger = Logger.new('foo.log', 10, 1024000)

I could not understand what actually the second parameter 10 will do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part from the [Logger docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html):

> Leave 10 “old log files”

When the current log file is switched, up to 10 older log files will be preserved. If after a log rotation there would be 11 files remaining, the oldest one will be deleted.

Comment: What needs to be done if i want to preserve all the old log files and create a new one?

Comment: I don't know how you would preserve **all** old log files and I am not sure whether it is possible. Neither does the documentation mention it, nor could I find any examples. I would just use a really high but sensible number, somewhere between 100 and 2000000000.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to try to preserve all the old log files. Disks have finite space, and the logger has the ability to create infinite files. Infinite > finite, which means your system will crash.

Comment: Sure, you are right, but the constructor of the logger might not be the right place  for the restriction, like you would not define the maximum number of records for each DB table in it's definition. I would rather create a cleanup job for that.